# Linking two tables based on timestamp interval

Tags: sql, data-science, presto

I am trying to join two tables that look like below:

A:

```
ID   |          Time        |   Mode
B121   2017-10-19 11:00:00     Processed
C232   2017-10-19 12:00:00     Cancelled
B121   2017-10-19 15:00:00     Cancelled
C455   2017-10-19 18:00:00     Processed
N776   2017-10-19 11:00:00     Processed
```

B:

```
ID   |          Time        
B121   2017-10-19 11:43:32    
C232   2017-10-19 12:00:00    
B121   2017-10-19 15:33:55    
C455   2017-10-19 18:31:33     
N776   2017-10-19 11:08:00
```

I want to add the Time, and Mode columns from table A to table B based on joining them on
ID and Time column.

But the times in table A are based on intervals for each hour and the times in table B are exact times.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? MySQL, Oracle etc.,?

Answer (score 2):

Try this below logic using [`date_trunc()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_trunc) to achieve your desired output. By using "hour" as parameter in the `date_trunc()` function, this will convert the date time to a value until Hours of the value. As a result, condition will only check up to Hour value is same or not.

```
SELECT B.ID, B.Time, A.Time, A.Mode 
FROM B
INNER JOIN A
    ON B.ID = A.ID
    AND date_trunc(hour, B.Time) =  date_trunc(hour, A.Time)
```